# Extracting significand and exponent for base-10 representation from decimal formatted string

Tags: python, performance, floating-point-conversion

I am looking for an efficient Python implementation of a function that takes a decimal formatted string, e.g.

```
2.05000
200
0.012
```

and returns a tuple of two integers representing the significand and exponent of the input in base-10 floating point format, e.g.

```
(205,-2)
(2,2)
(12,-3)
```

List comprehension would be a nice bonus.

I have a gut feeling that there exists an efficient (and possibly Pythonic) way of doing this but it eludes me...

---

### Solution applied to pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ser1 = pd.Series(['2.05000', '- 2.05000', '00 205', '-205', '-0', '-0.0', '0.00205', '0', np.nan])

ser1 = ser1.str.replace(' ', '')
parts = ser1.str.split('.').apply(pd.Series)

# remove all white spaces
# strip leading zeros (even those after a minus sign)
parts.ix[:,0] = '-'*parts.ix[:,0].str.startswith('-') + parts.ix[:,0].str.lstrip('-').str.lstrip('0')

parts.ix[:,1] = parts.ix[:,1].fillna('')        # fill non-existamt decimal places
exponents = -parts.ix[:,1].str.len()
parts.ix[:,0] += parts.ix[:,1]                  # append decimal places to digit before decimal point

parts.ix[:,1] = parts.ix[:,0].str.rstrip('0')   # strip following zeros

exponents += parts.ix[:,0].str.len() - parts.ix[:,1].str.len()

parts.ix[:,1][(parts.ix[:,1] == '') | (parts.ix[:,1] == '-')] = '0'
significands = parts.ix[:,1].astype(float)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'exponent': exponents, 'significand': significands})
df2
```

Input:

```
0      2.05000
1    - 2.05000
2       00 205
3         -205
4           -0
5         -0.0
6      0.00205
7            0
8          NaN
dtype: object
```

Output:

```
   exponent  significand
0        -2          205
1        -2         -205
2         0          205
3         0         -205
4         0            0
5         0            0
6        -5          205
7         0            0
8       NaN          NaN

[9 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: wouldn't the first one be `(2.05, 0)` and the third one be `(1.2, -2)`? Why does `2.05` become `205` and `200` become `2`?

Comment: @GP89 While (1.2,-2) is mathematically an equivalent representation, the whole idea of storing significant and exponent separately is that both can be stored as integers. Thus, for this application (12,-3) is the correct representation. Maybe http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point helps you understand this representation if I am doing a poor job of explaining.

Comment: Ok thanks, so is a requirement that it be stored as the smallest integer representation? (ie why `200` becomes `2`)

Comment: That's the reason I was confused. In that representation result isn't and integer, but a number `1 <= x < 10`

Comment: @GP89 I think you are confused by scientific notation. In science 205 would often be expressed as 2.05*10^2, in floating point storage however, 205 needs to be thought of as 205*10^0 so that significant and exponent are integers that can be stored efficiently. Does this help?

Comment: Ah I was being a bit dense. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straight-forward string processing solution.

```
def sig_exp(num_str):
    parts = num_str.split('.', 2)
    decimal = parts[1] if len(parts) > 1 else ''
    exp = -len(decimal)
    digits = parts[0].lstrip('0') + decimal
    trimmed = digits.rstrip('0')
    exp += len(digits) - len(trimmed)
    sig = int(trimmed) if trimmed else 0
    return sig, exp

>>> for x in ['2.05000', '200', '0.012', '0.0']:
    print sig_exp(x)

(205, -2)
(2, 2)
(12, -3)
(0, 0)
```

I'll leave the handling of negative numbers as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I love this solution if for no other reason than that it took me a second read through to understand the ingeneous copying, trimming & correction of the exponent resulting from the trailing digits of 2.05000...

Comment: Answer accepted as it can be implemented in vectorized form for pandas columns. Thanks again very much!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `decimal.Decimal`:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> s = '2.05000'
>>> x = Decimal(s)
>>> x
Decimal('2.05000')
>>> x.as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(2, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0), exponent=-5)
```

Does almost what you need, just convert the `DecimalTuple` to your desired Format, for example:

```
>>> t = Decimal('2.05000').as_tuple()
>>> (''.join(str(x) for i,x in enumerate(t.digits) if any(t.digits[i:])),
... t.exponent + sum(1 for i,x in enumerate(t.digits) if not 
... any (t.digits[i:])))
('205', -2)
```

Just a sketch, but satisfies your three testcases.

You might want to `.normalize()` your `Decimal` before you process it `.as_tuple()` (thanks @georg), this takes care of trailing zeros.
This way, you won't need to do that much formatting:

```
>>> Decimal('2.05000').normalize().as_tuple()
DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(2, 0, 5), exponent=-2)
```

So your function can be written as:

```
>>> def decimal_str_to_sci_tuple(s):
...  t = Decimal(s).normalize().as_tuple()
...  return (int(''.join(map(str,t.digits))), t.exponent)
... 
>>> decimal_str_to_sci_tuple('2.05000')
(205, -2)
>>> decimal_str_to_sci_tuple('200')
(2, 2)
>>> decimal_str_to_sci_tuple('0.012')
(12, -3)
```

(be sure to add t.sign when supporting negative numbers though).

Comment: I'd say `.normalize().as_tuple()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for scientific notation, you could use decimal and format as:

```
numbers = ['2.05000','200','0.01','111']
print ["{:.2E}".format(Decimal(n)) for n in numbers]
```

output:

```
['2.05E+0', '2.00E+2', '1.00E-2']
```

If you are looking for,

1. Get the digit other than 0 in the right hand side
2. Get the scientific notation till right hand side digit

   ```
   from decimal import  *
   numbers = ['2.05000','200','0.01','111']
   numbers = [ n.rstrip('0') if '.' in n else n  for n in numbers ] #strip right         zeros if found after .
   for n in numbers:
       if '.' in n:
           num = n.split('.')[0]
           dec = n.split('.')[1]
           tenthNumber = len(dec)
           print (Decimal(num+dec), -1 * tenthNumber)
       elif n.endswith('0'): 
           tenthNumber = 0
           revN = n[::-1]
           for i in range(len(revN)):
               if revN[i]=='0':
                   tenthNumber = tenthNumber + 1
               else:
                   break
           print (n[:(len(n)-tenthNumber)], str(tenthNumber))

       else:
           print (n,0)
   ```

Output:

```
(Decimal('205'), -2)
('2', '2')
(Decimal('1'), -2)
('111', 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method using [venpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889711/extracting-significand-and-exponent-for-base-10-representation-from-decimal-form/26891267#26891267)'s formatting string (as all credit goes to him) and starting with numbers instead of strings. If you can afford rounding the significand (e.g. after 2 digits), you could simply write:

```
def scd_exp(scnum):
    scnum = "{:.2e}".format(scnum)
    return (float(scnum[:4]),int(scnum[-3:]))


numbers = [2.05, 205, 0.0001576, 111]
for number in numbers:
    print(scd_exp(number))
```

result is

```
(2.05, 0)
(2.05, 2)
(1.58, -4)
(1.11, 2)
```

If you want to set the significand rounding by yourself each time you call the function (let's say to 6 digits for the example), you could write

```
def scd_exp(scnum, roundafter):
    formstr = "".join(("{:.",str(roundafter),"e}"))
    scnum = formstr.format(scnum)     
    return (float(scnum[:roundafter+2]),int(scnum[-3:]))


numbers = [2.05, 205, 0.000157595678, 111]
for number in numbers:
    print(scd_exp(number, 6))
```

which gives back

```
(2.05, 0)
(2.05, 2)
(1.575957, -4)
(1.11, 2)
```